# Setting up DispatcherServlet without init-param

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-web

Hey i'm trying to wire up multiple dispatcher servlets in my web application (one dispatcher servlet and one message dispatcher servlet actually). All these servlets need to share all my beans, so i'm wiring the application context as a context-param.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>apf-inflow</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>com.fmr.bpo.asyncprocessingframework.concentrator.wiring.configuration.pojo.SampleConfig</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>apf-inflow</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Since there's no bean that's just for the one dispatcher servlet, i've not put an init-param.

But when i don't specify a parameter, spring is gonna look for "/WEB-INF/servlet-name-servlet.xml", so i get this error:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/apf-inflow-servlet.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/apf-inflow-servlet.xml]

Is there any way i can tell the dispatcher to not look for the config (since i've already wired up a common config)?

**EDIT:**

Adding in the default location or explicitly pointing the dispatcher to an empty spring configuration file does fix the issue.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>apf-inflow</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.fmr.bpo.asyncprocessingframework.concentrator.wiring.configuration.pojo.BlankConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

But i don't really wanna put a dummy file in there to supress the error. I'd like to ask spring to stop looking for a file in the first place.

Comment: For a Web application, Spring has two application contexts, the web application context and the regular application context--offhand, it seems odd that you have no use for the former (maybe you're putting stuff in the latter that shouldn't be there?)  Did you wire in an empty web application context (you can use mine as a guide, just empty it: https://github.com/gmazza/tightblog/blob/trunk/app/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml) to confirm your webapp still runs fine?  If not (i.e., you do need web app configuration in that xml), your question is no longer necessary to ask.

Comment: Well i actually have two servlets which need to share beans, so i'm putting all my beans in the regular application context. (I have a spring integration application with one web service and one http inbound gateways. The web service endpoint needs a messagedispatcher and the http needs a regular dispatcherservlet. So essentially requests from both endpoints need to go through a common flow, and hence the former is empty.

Comment: Haven't tested this but if you configure your DispatcherServlets programmatically you may be able to get away with an empty [GenericWebApplicationContext](http://www.codota.com/java/spring/scenarios/549bbb72da0ac537bddfd304/org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext?tag=spring1b) instance. See [WebApplicationInitializer](http://kielczewski.eu/2013/11/spring-mvc-without-web-xml-using-webapplicationinitializer/) for wiring info.